# MongoDB return collections matching one element in query array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

This is the database collection - Job:

```
{
  "skillsRequired": ["html", "css", "javascript"],
  "qualification": [ "BE", "B-Tech"],
  "company" : "microsoft"
},
{
  "skillsRequired": ["html", "ml", "ai", "python"],
  "qualification": [ "BE", "B-Tech"],
  "company" : "microsoft"
},
{
  "skillsRequired": ["ml", "ai", "python"],
  "qualification": [ "BE", "B-Tech"],
  "company" : "microsoft"
}
```

How can I get the following output when parameter is **"skillsRequired" : ["html", "css"]**

```
[{
  "skillsRequired": ["html", "css", "javascript"],
  "qualification": [ "BE", "B-Tech"],
  "company" : "microsoft"
},
{
  "skillsRequired": ["html", "ml", "ai", "python"],
  "qualification": [ "BE", "B-Tech"],
  "company" : "microsoft"
}]
```

In short, the query should return all the records/documents in which any one of the elements in parameter query matches with that of the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const query = {};

if (skillsRequiredParam && skillsRequiredParam.length > 0) 
    query.skillsRequired = {$in: skillsRequiredParam}
}     
const docs = await db.collection.find(query).exec();
```

Comment: It is working as expected, but when the parameters **skillsRequired** array is empty, I want it to return all the documents since no conditions are provided. As of now if the parameters array is empty it is not returning any document.

Comment: Just passing {} as the query will get all the documents but as soon as put skillsRequired in there, you need to match some terms. Before the call put a check that the array is nonempty and if empty, don't add the query.